# Modify photo selected by UIImagePicker before it's used in the move-and-scale screen

Tags: iphone, image-manipulation, uiimagepickercontroller

as you probably know, the UIImagePickerController in the UIKit Framework allows the user to take a photo which is then handed over to my App for further processing.
If the property allowsEditing is set to YES, the user is allowed to move and scale the photo after taking it.

What I'd like to accomplish is to modify the photo in my code BEFORE the user is presented with the move and scale screen. This is because I'd like to add some visual effects to the photo and the user should be able to move and scale with these effects already applied to the photo.

I know that there's the cameraOverlayView property, but this is not useful in my case as far as I'm concerned.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: I think there is no official supported method to do that. The only way i see is to use method swizzling to replace the method called by the picker when it allows to modify image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so easy way is to implement *move and scale* functionality on your own.
make `showsCameraControls` NO. You can design your own preview screen (with modified Image).

Looks like there are issues with touches in IOS5 cameraOverlayView. Make sure the above solution works for IOS5 also :).